# Handbrake videos displayed letterboxed, how to avoid?

Tags: video, dvd, video-conversion, video-encoding, handbrake

I have encoded a DVD with HandBrake as `mkv` with one of the `GENERAL` (720p) presets. When I play this on my SONY TV (with the TV's function to play video files) it is shown letterboxed (black bar on top/bottom).

When I use `mp4` as target format (taken from as HandBrake's `DEVIVES/ANDROID` presets), it uses the full screen on my SONY TV.

1. How can I use `MKV` and obtain the same result?
2. Is it a particular setting in the `mkv` PRESET I need to set?

[image: Dimension settings]

I use exactly the same settings for `mp4` and `mkv`, only the file format varies.

**EDIT:** As Jan pointed out (whose comment got deleted) I have used the wrong encoding, so I have switched to 576p. Good point - thanks. Anyway, situation is the same. `mp4` full screen and `mkv` letterboxed on my Sony TV.

[image: Changed to 576p]

Comment: What aspect ratio is the original video? Are your resulting videos being cropped or displayed with an incorrect aspect ratio [stretched or squeezed]?

Comment: added screenshot, thanks for the question